# How to snap to sections in a WinJS.UI.Hub control

Tags: css, windows-8, windows-store-apps, winjs, windows-8.1

Is there a way in a Windows 8 app using HTML/JS to snap the user's panning of a Hub control only to each Hub Section so that the user always lands exactly on a section?

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the Snap Point Type from Proximity to Mandatory:

```
.win-hub-viewport {
    -ms-scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466057.aspx

Possible values are:

- **none:** Initial value. Panning and scrolling are unaffected by any defined snap-points. Touch flicks will result in normal inertia.
- **proximity:** When normal inertia would leave content near a snap point, inertia is adjusted to land exactly on the snap point. However, it is still possible to land between snap points.
- **mandatory:** Inertia is adjusted to ensure content always lands on a snap point.